# Is there a tool to check the minimum privileges required for a set of sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, permissions

If I have a set of SQL (ie. a script containing arbitrary SQL statements), is there any way of finding out what the minimum permissions are required to execute the SQL?

*(I'm thinking of something similar to the "Permissions required by the application" area in Visual Studio when viewing the Security tab on the project properties page of a WinForms application.)*

A bit of background:

As part of an application, I have a set of upgrade scripts (which alter the data in tables as well as altering the schema) which will get run against a customer's database at their end. I want to analyse these upgrade scripts for any potential permission problems before I deploy them, as the customer running them may have a restricted login to SQL Server. The types of things that happen in these scripts are typically adding/removing/altering tables/columns/indices, but I also do select from the informational schema views and the system tables.

**EDIT:**

I have error handling in place to cope with those occasions when a user doesn't have the correct permissions to do an upgrade. I am also currently checking that the user running the upgrade is `db_owner`, but I'm more concerned with things outside the database being upgraded. For example, scripts quite often use the system tables to get information about the database schema to decide whether to do a specific action - I'd like to know what permissions are needed to access these tables. Another example is turning on page compression - does the user need specific permissions to do this?

I'd like to do the check on the upgrade scripts before deploying them, as it is a much better user experience to be aware that you need certain permissions beforehand, rather than the upgrade just failing with an error.

Comment: +1 our dba (mcdba an mct) did not help me with same thing and I some times ago ended up with transaction and checking for special error number

Comment: I do have error trapping wrapped around where this SQL executes, but I'd like to be able to know beforehand what permissions are required rather than have it fail and then find out it is due to an under-privileged user attempting to run it.

Comment: at least you can check for sysdba or dbowner :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a command exists.

I would recommend the upgrade account be set to db_owner and have them run the script.  Keep it simple.  Or ship a role in your db for this purpose.

Maybe you could create a 'pre-execute' phase which tries to execute some commands and then rolls them back.  It would throw some errors if you didn't have access.  Quite a kludge though.

Comment: I like the pre-execute phase idea, though it would require me to know what to try beforehand - if I knew that I'd already know what permissions I would need.

Comment: "if I knew that I'd already know what permissions I would need."  so bottom line is that you're going to have to document your application's security needs and make those checks if you want the functionality you desire.  IMHO it's not worth it when you could instruct them to be db_owner in the userdb and master and be done with it.

Comment: I am trying hard to avoid that as the users are users in a large company where to make any IT changes (like changing role membership in sql server) requires an IT ticket which takes possibly weeks to complete. Additionally, I don't think they would even be allowed to be `db_owner` in the master database.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of the same thing.  It would be great if there was some option in SQL profiler that would allow you to trace what permissions were used.  That way you could just grant a login sysadmin then have the user/application run through it's paces and remove any permissions that were not used.

What about...  If you did a profiler trace and saved it as a SQL Script then had something work through each statement in the trace to determine required permissions?

As a byproduct you'd end up with a handy script that would (in theory) function as a test of all functions that could be used to monitor the status of an application.